# How to invoke HTTP POST method over SSL in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssl, curl, https

So here's the request using curl:

```
curl -XPOST -H content-type:application/json -d "{\"credentials\":{\"username\":\"username\",\"key\":\"key\"}}" https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.1/auth
```

I've been trying to make this same request using ruby, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried a couple of libraries also, but I can't get it to work.
Here's what I have so far:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/v1.1/auth")
request.set_form_data({'credentials' => {'username' => 'username', 'key' => 'key'}})
response = http.request(request)
```

I get a 415 unsupported media type error.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are close, but not quite there.  Try something like this instead:

```
uri = URI.parse("https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/v1.1/auth")
request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.body = {'credentials' => {'username' => 'username', 'key' => 'key'}}.to_json
response = http.request(request)
```

This will set the Content-Type header as well as post the JSON in the body, rather than in the form data as your code had it.  With the sample credentials, it still fails, but I suspect it should work with real data in there.

Comment: CAn you help me with this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771177/post-request-not-working-rest?noredirect=1#comment31132280_20771177

Comment: I suggested an edit for `.to_json` at the end of the `request.body` line to avoid encoding errors. Thanks for the great answer though!

Comment: Awesome! Took me forever to find this solution, but thankfully I found this post.

Comment: @Eugene In the second last line, why are we passing the parameters in the body.. shouldn't we do that as a Query parameter? Also, I would like to know how to pass the same as query parameter.

Comment: Because POST requests require the content be sent in the body as opposed to query parameters which are mostly just for GET operations, although they are valid for a few others. POST and PUT require a body though.

Comment: @Eugene,
My requirement is to send few query parameters in the POST request, 
For eg - someurl/token?grant_type=client_credentials. How to do that?

Comment: You should be able to do that just as you would for a GET request `?grant_type=client_credentials` but you will need to make sure your `Content-Length` header is only calculated using the body, and not including the parameters set in the query string.  If you are having problems, you should ask a new question about it with more details.

Comment: Please be careful as using `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` introduces a security flow. You are vulnerable to an [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by skipping the SSL certificate verification.

Answer (score 4):

There's a very good explanation of how to make a JSON POST request with Net::HTTP [at this link](https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace).

I would recommend using a library like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty). It's well-documented, you can just set up your class like so:

```
class RackSpaceClient
  include HTTParty

  base_uri "https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/"
  format :json
  headers 'Accept' => 'application/json'

  #methods to do whatever

end
```

It looks like the main difference between the Ruby code you placed there, and the curl request, is that the curl request is POSTing JSON (content-type application/json) to the endpoint, whereas `request.set_form_data` is going to send a form in the body of the POST request (content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). You have to make sure the content going both ways is of type application/json.

Answer (score 3):

Another example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'

full_url = "http://" + options[:artifactory_url] + "/" + "api/build/promote/" + options[:build]

puts "Artifactory url: #{full_url}"

data = {
    status: "staged",
    comment: "Tested on all target platforms.",
    ciUser: "builder",
    #timestamp: "ISO8601",
    dryRun: false,
    targetRepo: "#{options[:target]}",
    copy: true,
    artifacts: true,
    dependencies: false,
    failFast: true,
}

uri = URI.parse(full_url)
headers = {'Content-Type' => "application/json", 'Accept-Encoding'=> "gzip,deflate",'Accept' => "application/json" }
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, headers)
request.basic_auth(options[:user], options[:password])
request.body = data.to_json
response = http.request(request)

puts response.code
puts response.body
```

Answer (score 3):

All others are too long here is a **ONE LINER**:

```
Net::HTTP.start('auth.api.rackspacecloud.com', :use_ssl => true).post(
      '/v1.1/auth', {:credentials => {:username => "username",:key => "key"}}.to_json,
      initheader={'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
    )
```

* `to_json` needs `require 'json'`

---

OR if you want to

- **NOT** verify the hosts
- be more readable
- ensure the connection is closed once you're done

then:

```
ssl_opts={:use_ssl => true, :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}
Net::HTTP.start('auth.api.rackspacecloud.com', ssl_opts) { |secure_connection|
  secure_connection.post(
      '/v1.1/auth', {:credentials => {:username => "username",:key => "key"}}.to_json,
      initheader={'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
    )
}
```

In case it's tough to remember what params go where:

- SSL options are per connection so you specify them while opening the connection.
- You can reuse the connection for multiple REST calls to same base url. Think of thread safety of course.
- Header is a "request header" and hence specified per request. I.e. in calls to `get`/`post`/`patch`/`...`.
- `HTTP.start()`: Creates a new Net::HTTP object, then additionally opens the TCP connection and HTTP session.
- `HTTP.new()`: Creates a new Net::HTTP object without opening a TCP connection or HTTP session.