# POST Request in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, post, request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make this HTTP POST request in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919287/make-this-http-post-request-in-ruby)

How do you perform the following JavaScript request in Ruby?

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/';
data 'name=aren&age=22';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",

    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out HTTParty, great gem https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Example:

```
response = HTTParty.post(url, body: data)
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

Although I believe it is synchronous- dont quote me on that though