# Post request not working rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rest, ssl

I have this form and when i submit it with my username and password the login works:

```
<form action="https://website.de/login/index.php" method="post" >
              <input name="username" id="username" size="14" type="text">
              <input name="password" id="password" size="14" value="" type="password">
              <input id="loginbtn" value="Login" type="submit">        
</form>
```

Now i tried to login into the website with rest-client:

```
require 'rest_client'

response = RestClient.post 'https://website.de/login/index.php', :username => 'Horst', :password => 'Secret'
puts response.code
```

Somehow this wont work i get the status code 200 but a successful login would be 303! 
I believe the problem is that its not a `http` but a `https` so how do i have to add ssl?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think status code 200 means the request failed? In case of a status code 303, RestClient follows the redirect and transforms the request into GET.

Comment: It redirects me to a site where it says i entered a false password!

Comment: The "Response Codes" section at http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/urls might be relevant.  I'm getting familiar with these things for one of my own projects.

Comment: Just a hint, the login site may be looking for some browser headers such as `Referrer` or `User-Agent`.